# Automatically show subtitles when playing embedded Facebook video

Tags: wordpress, facebook, embedded-video

I have uploaded a video to Facebook and I added subtitles by adding a SRT file.
When played from Facebook, the subtitles are shown automatically.

I used the code generated on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player to embed the video in a post on my Wordpress website:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-video" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/Superkidz.nl/videos/1006129069467171/" data-width="500"></div>
```

However when I play the video from my website, the subtitles are not shown automatically. The subtitles can be selected manually though.

Anybody know a way to show the subtitles automatically when playing the video?